# How to find a string within a string Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I would like to run a query to find the string within the 2 brackets of a another string:
Example of string : Brand: E[WALDO]

Return = WALDO

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mid(strSource, 
       InStr(1, strSource, "[") + 1, 
       InStr(strSource, "]") - InStr(strSource, "[") - 1)
```

Comment: What if there is something before the string? or After: example - Size: S[25MM]; Colour: S[BLUE]; Brand: E[WALDO] - how do I find "BRAND" ?

Comment: InStr has parameter "Start", you can use it for skipping square brackets before occurence you need. In your case use as first parameter `InStr(1, strSource, "Brand:")` instead of "1" in all 3 `InStr` functions. Symbols after will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks so much! Really helped me tons!